# How to use ffmpeg lib transform mp4(h264&aac) to m3u8 (hls) by C code?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I used official examples `transcoding.c` but console print `pkt->duration = 0, maybe the hls segment duration will not precise`.

I use this code to set duration but invalid。

`av_opt_set_int(ofmt_ctx->priv_data, "hls_time", 5, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);`

In command line

`ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment -segment_list a.m3u8 -segment_time 10 a-%03d.ts`

How to use C code to achieve this command?

this is my code:

```c
/**
 * @file
 * API example for demuxing, decoding, filtering, encoding and muxing
 * @example transcoding.c
 */

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>

static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
typedef struct FilteringContext {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
} FilteringContext;
static FilteringContext *filter_ctx;

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;
} StreamContext;
static StreamContext *stream_ctx;

static int open_input_file(const char *filename) {
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    stream_ctx = av_mallocz_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*stream_ctx));
    if (!stream_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        if (!dec) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to find decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context "
                                       "for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
        /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
            /* Open decoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx = codec_ctx;
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, filename, 0);
    return 0;
}

static int open_output_file(const char *filename, enum AVCodecID videoCodecId, enum AVCodecID audioCodecId) {
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, *enc_ctx;
    AVCodec *encoder;
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not create output context\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        }

        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        dec_ctx = stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx;

        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {

            if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(videoCodecId);
            } else {
                encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(audioCodecId);
            }
            //encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            /* In this example, we transcode to same properties (picture size,
             * sample rate etc.). These properties can be changed for output
             * streams easily using filters */
            if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
                enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
                enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                if (encoder->pix_fmts)
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
                else
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;
                /* video time_base can be set to whatever is handy and supported by encoder */
                enc_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dec_ctx->framerate);
            } else {
                enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate;
                enc_ctx->channel_layout = dec_ctx->channel_layout;
                enc_ctx->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(enc_ctx->channel_layout);
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                enc_ctx->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
                enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational) {1, enc_ctx->sample_rate};
            }

            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            /* Third parameter can be used to pass settings to encoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, enc_ctx);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }

            out_stream->time_base = enc_ctx->time_base;
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx = enc_ctx;
        } else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Elementary stream #%d is of unknown type, cannot proceed\n", i);
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        } else {
            /* if this stream must be remuxed */
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Copying parameters for stream #%u failed\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;
        }

    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, filename, 1);

    av_opt_set_int(ofmt_ctx->priv_data, "hls_time", 5, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not open output file '%s'", filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /* init muxer, write output file header */
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filter(FilteringContext *fctx, AVCodecContext *dec_ctx,
                       AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, const char *filter_spec) {
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    const AVFilter *buffersrc = NULL;
    const AVFilter *buffersink = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
                 "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
                 dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                 dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
                 dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
                 dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                           args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                                           NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts",
                             (uint8_t *) &enc_ctx->pix_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->pix_fmt),
                             AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
            goto end;
        }
    } else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        if (!dec_ctx->channel_layout)
            dec_ctx->channel_layout =
                    av_get_default_channel_layout(dec_ctx->channels);
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
                 "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%"PRIx64,
                 dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den, dec_ctx->sample_rate,
                 av_get_sample_fmt_name(dec_ctx->sample_fmt),
                 dec_ctx->channel_layout);
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                           args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                                           NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_fmts",
                             (uint8_t *) &enc_ctx->sample_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_fmt),
                             AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample format\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "channel_layouts",
                             (uint8_t *) &enc_ctx->channel_layout,
                             sizeof(enc_ctx->channel_layout), AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output channel layout\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_rates",
                             (uint8_t *) &enc_ctx->sample_rate, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_rate),
                             AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample rate\n");
            goto end;
        }
    } else {
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    /* Endpoints for the filter graph. */
    outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx = 0;
    outputs->next = NULL;

    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx = 0;
    inputs->next = NULL;

    if (!outputs->name || !inputs->name) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
                                        &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* Fill FilteringContext */
    fctx->buffersrc_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    fctx->buffersink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    fctx->filter_graph = filter_graph;

    end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

static int init_filters(void) {
    const char *filter_spec;
    unsigned int i;
    int ret;
    filter_ctx = av_malloc_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*filter_ctx));
    if (!filter_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        filter_ctx[i].buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].buffersink_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].filter_graph = NULL;
        if (!(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
              || ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            continue;


        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            filter_spec = "null"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for video */
        else
            filter_spec = "anull"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for audio */
        ret = init_filter(&filter_ctx[i], stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx,
                          stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx, filter_spec);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int encode_write_frame(AVFrame *filt_frame, unsigned int stream_index, int *got_frame) {
    int ret;
    int got_frame_local;
    AVPacket enc_pkt;
    int (*enc_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVPacket *, const AVFrame *, int *) =
    (ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type ==
     AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_encode_video2 : avcodec_encode_audio2;

    if (!got_frame)
        got_frame = &got_frame_local;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding frame\n");
    /* encode filtered frame */
    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
    enc_pkt.size = 0;
    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);
    ret = enc_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx, &enc_pkt,
                   filt_frame, got_frame);
    av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;
    if (!(*got_frame))
        return 0;

    /* prepare packet for muxing */
    enc_pkt.stream_index = stream_index;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt,
                         stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->time_base,
                         ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
    /* mux encoded frame */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
    return ret;
}

static int filter_encode_write_frame(AVFrame *frame, unsigned int stream_index) {
    int ret;
    AVFrame *filt_frame;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pushing decoded frame to filters\n");
    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersrc_ctx,
                                       frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    while (1) {
        filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!filt_frame) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            break;
        }
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pulling filtered frame from filters\n");
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersink_ctx,
                                      filt_frame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            /* if no more frames for output - returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)
             * if flushed and no more frames for output - returns AVERROR_EOF
             * rewrite retcode to 0 to show it as normal procedure completion
             */
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                ret = 0;
            av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
            break;
        }

        filt_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;
        ret = encode_write_frame(filt_frame, stream_index, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int flush_encoder(unsigned int stream_index) {
    int ret;
    int got_frame;

    if (!(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->codec->capabilities &
          AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY))
        return 0;

    while (1) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Flushing stream #%u encoder\n", stream_index);
        ret = encode_write_frame(NULL, stream_index, &got_frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        if (!got_frame)
            return 0;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    char *inputFile = "D:/20200623_094923.mp4";
    char *outputFile = "D:/test/te.m3u8";
    enum AVCodecID videoCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    enum AVCodecID audioCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_AAC;

    int ret;
    AVPacket packet = {.data = NULL, .size = 0};
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int (*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);

    if ((ret = open_input_file(inputFile)) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file(outputFile, videoCodec, audioCodec)) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters()) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;
        stream_index = packet.stream_index;
        type = ifmt_ctx->streams[packet.stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n",
               stream_index);

        if (filter_ctx[stream_index].filter_graph) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Going to reencode&filter the frame\n");
            frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frame) {
                ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                break;
            }
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                                 ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                                 stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx->time_base);
            dec_func = (type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_decode_video2 :
                       avcodec_decode_audio4;
            ret = dec_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx, frame,
                           &got_frame, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                break;
            }

            if (got_frame) {
                frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                ret = filter_encode_write_frame(frame, stream_index);
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto end;
            } else {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
            }
        } else {
            /* remux this frame without reencoding */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                                 ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                                 ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    /* flush filters and encoders */
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        /* flush filter */
        if (!filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            continue;
        ret = filter_encode_write_frame(NULL, i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing filter failed\n");
            goto end;
        }

        /* flush encoder */
        ret = flush_encoder(i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing encoder failed\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
    end:
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
        if (filter_ctx && filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            avfilter_graph_free(&filter_ctx[i].filter_graph);
    }
    av_free(filter_ctx);
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    if (ret < 0)
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```